# Firefox for Android input file onchange doesn't trigger when using camera

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, upload, camera

I am making a single picture form that should auto upload when the image is selected.

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="{{ bucket }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="pic-form">
    <label>
    <img src="placeholder.png" class="photo"/>
    <input type="file" name="file" required id="pic-file" accept="image/"/>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit-btn"/>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#pic-file').on('change', function(evt){
    $('#pic-form').submit();
});
```

It works fine on desktop, and on my phone it also triggers when I select a picture from my library but not when I select from camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bug on the `accept` parameter. In my actual code I had "image/;capture=camera" where the HTML spec says it is a comma separated list. I had to change to "image/,capture=camera". At the end I ended up with this:

```
<input type="file" name="file" 
    required id="pic-file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,capture=camera"/>
```